# Is there always an accumulator to replace append/3? [SOLVED]

Tags: prolog

Can  append/3 at the end of this code

```
provable(F, P) :- prove([] > [F], P).

% axiom
prove(G > D, ax(G > D, A)) :- member(A,G), member(B,D), A == B, !.

% implication
prove(G > D, limpl(G > D, P1,P2)) :- select1((A => B),G,G1), !,
                prove(G1 > [A|D], P1), prove([B|G1] > D, P2).

prove(G > D, rimpl(G > D, P)) :- select1((A => B),D,D1), !,
                prove([A|G] > [B|D1], P).

% negation
prove(G > D, lneg(G > D, P)) :- select1( ~A,G,G1), !,
                prove(G1 > [A|D], P).

prove(G > D, rneg(G > D, P)) :- select1(~A ,D,D1), !,
                prove([A|G] > D1, P).

% -----------------------------------------------------------------
select1(X,L,L1) :- append(L2,[X|L3],L), append(L2,L3,L1).
% -----------------------------------------------------------------
```

be replaced by an accumulator?  (This code is a part of leanseq.pl a  A sequent calculus prover implemented in Prolog, by Jens Otten, and I am surprised by the choice of append, instead of an accumulator, hence my question, because my all my tentatives to replace append failed.)

Comment: Have you seen the [implementation of `select/3`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/lists.pl?show=src#select/3)? The question in the title though, not sure about what you really mean.

Comment: @TA_intern , I just quoted more code, I hope it helps.

Comment: Did you try to replace `select1/3` with `select/3` that comes with library(lists)?

Comment: Just to be explicit about it, I don't see how the definition of `select1/3` from your question is any better than `select/3` from library(lists). I have no idea how you have tried to replace `append/3`, nor do I know why the author of this code did not use `select/3` but implemented their own.

Comment: Now that I read more carefully, the intrinsically non-deterministic select is followed by cuts in this code, difficult to understand the thought process of the programmer. This is however universally true so....

Comment: @TA_intern  I made a mistake somewhere. Yes, the replacement of select1/3 by select/3 that comes with library(lists) works and improves performances. Thanks ! I consider this question as solved for this code.

Comment: It is quite possible that the original `select1/3` is faster than `select/3` in some implementations because  `append/3` has often been hand-coded to produce a favorable LIPS-rating. Otherwise they are the same.

Comment: @false if you mean the double append implementation, I am somewhat surprised; can you point to an implementation of the append + Prolog where this is the case? Purely out of curiosity on my side.